# How to disable snowflake OCSP validation while connecting from kafka-snowflake sink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect, ocsp

We are trying to push data from kafka topics to snowflake using sink connectors. But we are unable to create the connector and seeing the below warning
`SEVERE: WARNING!!! Using fail-open to connect. Driver is connecting to an HTTPS endpoint without OCSP based Certificate Revocation checking as it could not obtain a valid OCSP Response to use from the CA OCSP responder. Details:`

How can we bypass this certification validation/checking?

Comment: This is just a warning and when OCSP is set to FAIL OPEN (default) connection will still go through. There will only be a slight delay establishing the connection.

Comment: @Sergiu Thanks for the response. We are unable to create connector and seeing timeouts . When we went through logs we found above warning

Comment: The above warning is not enough, do you have anything else in the log?

Comment: I am seeing the below response in logs:
{
    "cacheEnabled": true,
    "ocspReqBase64": "******",
    "ocspMode": "FAIL_OPEN",
    "sfcPeerHost": "**********",
    "ocspResponderURL": "http://ocsp.sca1b.amazontrust.com",
    "cacheHit": false,
    "eventType": "OCSPValidationError",
    "certId": "*********"
}

Comment: Yes, but that should not cause the connection to fail. Are you able to provide  a snippet of the log (maybe remove any private information)?

Comment: I am unable to attach the snippet here. But this is how the logs looks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251385/discussion-between-srikanth-kantamaneni-and-sergiu).

Comment: See also https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Snowflake-Connector-OCSP-checking-fails